# Dynamically setting readonly_fields in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

Can I change `readonly_fields` in my `TranslationAdmin` class dependent on the value of a certain field in the `Translation` being viewed? If so, how would I do that?

The only thing I've come up with is to make a widget that looks at the `Translation` and decides whether to be a readonly widget or not, but that seems like overkill for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can inherit the function get_readonly_fields() in your admin and set readonly fields according your model's certain field value

```
 class TranslationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...

        def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            if obj.certainfield == something:
                return ('field1', 'field2')
            else:
                return super(TranslationAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of:

- Creating a ModelAdmin (GISDataFileAdmin) with readonly_fields
- Inheriting from that ModelAdmin (ShapefileSetAdmin) and adding an additional value to readonly_fields

  ```
  class GISDataFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

      # Note(!): this is a list, NOT a tuple
      readonly_fields = ['modified', 'created', 'md5',]

  class ShapefileSetAdmin(GISDataFileAdmin):    

      def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
          # inherits readonly_fields from GISDataFileAdmin and adds another

          # retrieve current readonly fields 
          ro_fields = super(ShapefileSetAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)

          # check if new field already exists, if not, add it
          #
          # Note: removing the 'if not' check will add the new read-only field
          #   each time you go to the 'add' page in the admin
          #   e.g., you can end up with:
          # ['modified', 'created', 'md5', 'shapefile_load_path', 'shapefile_load_path, 'shapefile_load_path', etc.]
          #
          if not 'shapefile_load_path' in ro_fields:
              ro_fields.append('shapefile_load_path')

          return ro_fields
  ```