# Making a read-only field editable with the django admin interface

Tags: python, django

I am using the admin interface for handling models. There, I am setting some user profile fields as read-only fields in django.

```
readonly_fields = ('mobile_number',)
```

When I wish to change the mobile number in a user profile, I'm unable to modify it. How can I change a read-only field into an editable field by using the django admin interface? How can I add a button for specific models?

Comment: maybe this is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962694/dynamically-setting-readonly-fields-in-django-admin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to better match the wording. I also fixed some minor grammatica issues to make it a more pleasant read to whoever could have an answer. Good luck finding one!